# Setting Up Squid Proxy Server With A Different Gateway

Tags: squid

I have a problem in my networking study.

There's a network that has 192.168.0.1 as the router gateway. All of the client's PCs are in a same network (used IP are 192.168.103-110). And then I want to set up a squid proxy to do some caching activities. I don't have any difficulties in setting up the squid server, but my problem is, this squid server has a different IP (192.168.1.10) and gateway (192.168.1.1).
It always refuses any connections, I think it's because the local network itself has a different gateway with squid server.

How can I set up this correctly so it won't makes any trouble? Or I only can do it if I change this squid server IP to another IP within local network IP range? (I have successfully developed it when the squid server was using IP 192.168.0.106, but always fails when using 192.168.1.10).

Comment: If you add the .0.X network into your localnets ACL in squid, it should at least not refuse connections (I assume that it is squid, not iptables)..

Comment: Do you mean this : acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
If so, I've added it. It's a default config.

Comment: So what refuses the connection exactly?

Comment: When I applied this squid in my PC proxy settings, my browser only displaying "connection refused". Squid access.log only contained TCP_MISS 503 report.

Comment: I'm wondering if it might be a routing issue then, does the 192.168.1.1 router know about 192.168.0.x?

Comment: Actually my router is in 192.168.0.x, 192.168.1.1 is my squid server gateway. About the routing, they are configured well in my routerboard and I've tried to accessed the internet when I configured them. This issue just appear after I built this squid box.

Comment: Can you tell me how traffic gets from 192.168.0.x to 192.168.1.x ? Also, does squid know about this router (if it isn't 192.168.1.1) ?

Comment: For 192.168.0.x to 192.168.1.x I don't know much, but I've tried to ping 192.168.1.10 (squid) from my PC 192.168.0.103, it's answering. And also I always uses this PC to configure that squid box using SSH. Squid know about this router, before it's built as a squid box, it's an ordinary PC to access internet.

Comment: Hmm, I was just wondering if there were multiple routes to get between the two networks, often traffic going out one, but back in another can upset the machines receiving it..

Comment: Please give all the "acl" lines from your squid.conf which have IP addresses in them.

Comment: acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16
acl localnet src fc00::/7
acl localnet src fe80::/10